# How to list values from column A where column B is NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (let's call it df) that looks a bit like this:

```
Offer | Cancelled | Restriction
------|-----------|------------
1     | N         | A
2     | Y         | B
3     | N         | NaN
4     | Y         | NaN
```

I have the following bit of code, which creates a list of all offers that have been cancelled:

```
cancelled = list('000'+df.loc[(df['Cancelled']=='Y'),'Offer'].astype(str))
```

What I now want to do is to adapt this to create a list of all offers where the 'Restriction' column is not NaN. So my desired result would look like this:

```
['0001','0002']
```

Does anyone know how to do this please?

Comment: With [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html#pandas-series-notna)? `new = list('000'+df.loc[(df['Restriction'].notna()),'Offer'].astype(str))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Just add the extra condition that the Restriction column may not be NaN.

```
list('000'+df.loc[(df['Restriction'].notna()) & (df['Cancelled'] == 'Y'), 'Offer'].astype(str))
```

If you just want to filter on not NaN in Restriction column, the answer is commented by @Henry Ecker